# Windows folder path send over mail gets corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In my company we typical send mails containing paths to network drives, with project related stuff in them.

The problem arises when the folder name contains spaces ie. 
"z:\some name\stuff", the white space gets converted to something else in the mail, and rendering the path invalid.

I (thought i) identified the white space char to be unicode 160, and thus  to create a script to sort it out:

`input.replace(/[^\w]/g, String.fromCharCode(160));`

but its still invalid, so i guess its some other char.

Maybe the question is how do we share paths and retain the integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Microsoft Outlook, [you can send file paths with spaces if you use opening and closing chevrons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-links-containing-spaces-to-an-e-mail-message-65e3086b-8f1c-4e4c-88ab-7489b3c823b1) around the path like this:

```
<z:\some name\stuff>
```

Or, like it says in the note on that page, you can enter hyperlinks using the insert hyperlink tool which won't affect the path to your file:

[image]

Comment: +1, I have used Outlook for 2 decades, didn't even know this until a few weeks ago.